# How to create DataTable based on dynamic row and columns list?

Tags: html, datatable, datatables

I want to create Grid using DataTable JQuery. Here I will have dynamics columns that means I don't have predefined columns. Normally, when I have predefined columns, I just create Table and apply `ToDataTable()` method to convert in DataTable. But here I will have dynamic columns. One way is to iterate through columns and create Table Cell. Is there any other easy way?

Here is example,

```
{
  "Rows": [
    {
      "Columns": [
        {
          "DisplayName": "First Name",  
          "Value": "Ema",
        },
        {
          "DisplayName": "Last Name",
          "Value": "Sherik",
        }
        {
          "DisplayName": "Status",
          "Value": "Active",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Columns": [
        {
          "DisplayName": "First Name",
          "Value": "Jack",
        },
        {
          "DisplayName": "Last Name",
          "Value": "Mark",
        },
        {
          "DisplayName": "Status",
          "Value": "Active",
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
  "TotalRows": 2,
}
```

Comment: is your source an array of arrays or array of objects?

Comment: @naveen it will be array of objects. But I can change if it will be easy to implement.

Comment: It may help if you clarify how you are currently getting the data. In addition, I am not sure if I follow your comment… _”it will be array of objects. But I can change if it will be easy to implement”_? … If you can “change” it, then could you not “change” it to a `DataTable`? In other words, what is preventing you from “changing” it to a `DataTable` if you CAN “change” it?

Comment: @JohnG `1-` Data is coming from WEB API. In the API call request, I send name of the Entity and columns. WEB API provide me data with columns I have requested. The JSON I have added in question is response of the API call. `2-` When I say change, I mean if there is way I can just supply JSON to DataTable, I can do that but I don't know what format I need to pass. If there any other way rather iterate to each object of column, I can deserialize JSON and change. Please guide me.